# UItableview cellforrowatindexpath not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview

the code below not being called.

Header File

```
#import "SASlideMenuViewController.h"
#import "SASlideMenuDataSource.h"
#import "SASlideMenuDelegate.h"
#import "spHomeViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIColor+CustomColor.h"
@interface spMenuViewController : SASlideMenuViewController<SASlideMenuDataSource,SASlideMenuDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property NSMutableArray *menuArray;

@end





#import "spMenuViewController.h"
@interface spMenuViewController ()<SASlideMenuDataSource,SASlideMenuDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat selectedHue;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat selectedBrightness;

@end

@implementation spMenuViewController

@synthesize selectedHue;
@synthesize selectedBrightness;

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.selectedBrightness = 0.3;
        self.selectedHue = 0.0;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)tap:(id)sender{

}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SASlideMenuDataSource

-(void) prepareForSwitchToContentViewController:(UINavigationController *)content{
    UIViewController* controller = [content.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[spHomeViewController class]]) {
        spHomeViewController* coloredViewController = (spHomeViewController*) controller;
    }
}

// It configure the menu button. The beahviour of the button should not be modified
-(void) configureMenuButton:(UIButton *)menuButton{
    menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 29);
    [menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuicon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

// It configure the right menu button. The beahviour of the button should not be modified
-(void) configureRightMenuButton:(UIButton *)menuButton{
    menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 29);
    [menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuiconright"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

// This is the segue you want visibile when the controller is loaded the first time
-(NSIndexPath*) selectedIndexPath{
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
}

// It maps each indexPath to the segueId to be used. The segue is performed only the first time the controller needs to loaded, subsequent switch to the content controller will use the already loaded controller

-(NSString*) segueIdForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString* result;
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            result = @"segueHome";
            break;
        case 1:
            result = @"segueHome";
            break;
        default:
            result = @"segueHome";
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

-(Boolean) disableContentViewControllerCachingForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

-(Boolean) hasRightMenuForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 3;
}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Red";
    }else if (section == 1){
        return @"Green";
    }else {
        return @"Blue";
    }
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 4;
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat brightness = 1-((double) indexPath.row)/5;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    CGFloat hue=0;
    if (section == 0) {
        hue = 0.0;
    }else if (section==1){
        hue = 0.33;
    }else if (section==2){
        hue = 0.66;
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0 brightness:brightness alpha:1.0];
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"item"];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) leftMenuVisibleWidth{
    return 260;
}

-(CGFloat) rightMenuVisibleWidth{
    return 260;
}

//restricts pan gesture interation to 50px on the left and right of the view.
-(Boolean) shouldRespondToGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) gesture forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    CGPoint touchPosition = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    return (touchPosition.x < 50.0 || touchPosition.x > self.view.bounds.size.width - 50.0f);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat brightness = 1-((double) indexPath.row)/5;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    CGFloat hue=0;
    if (section == 0) {
        hue = 0.0;
    }else if (section==1){
        hue = 0.33;
    }else if (section==2){
        hue = 0.66;
    }
    self.selectedHue = hue;
    self.selectedBrightness = brightness;
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SASlideMenuDelegate

-(void) slideMenuWillSlideIn:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuWillSlideIn");
}
-(void) slideMenuDidSlideIn:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuDidSlideIn");
}
-(void) slideMenuWillSlideToSide:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuWillSlideToSide");
}
-(void) slideMenuDidSlideToSide:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuDidSlideToSide");
}
-(void) slideMenuWillSlideOut:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuWillSlideOut");
}
-(void) slideMenuDidSlideOut:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuDidSlideOut");
}
-(void) slideMenuWillSlideToLeft:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuWillSlideToLeft");
}
-(void) slideMenuDidSlideToLeft:(UINavigationController *)selectedContent{
    NSLog(@"slideMenuDidSlideToLeft");
}

@end
```

Comment: have you set your tableview's delegate and datasource?

Comment: did you conform to the delegate protocol in the header?

Comment: sorry. i don't get what you mean

Comment: can you post your header file as well please?

Comment: Does it show any error message or assertion failure?

Comment: I suspect "cell = [self.tableView"  as NOK. Try to remove self. from there, it looks like that's an inherited property from SASlideMenuViewController. And to be safe, drag an outlet for your tableview and set the delegate/datasource in code. And as John said, add UITableViewDelegate protocol @ top of your header as well (near UITableViewDataSource). If you don't use storyboard or xib, set in viewdidload self.tableView.delegate = self, self.tableView.dataSource = self.

Comment: @interface spMenuViewController : SASlideMenuViewController<SASlideMenuDataSource,SASlideMenuDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make SASlideMenuViewController as datasource of the UITableView ?

Check the code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

or connecting File's owner as a datasource of your table view in Xib.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just set `UITableView.dataSource` but not `UITableView.delegate`. Set it in your xib.
and you should implement the method below:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and it must return a positive number.